# How to insert dynamically created textboxes with the same name into database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, database

This is my html code.  It dynamically creates these textboxes but they all have the same name.

```
  <?php
include 'db.php';
$office = $_GET['office'];
$application_name = $_GET['application_name'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Add Requirements for New Application</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
           <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
           <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Bootstrap css library -->

</head>

<style>



.header--banner {
    background-image: url(cb.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
.header--banner {

height: 45.5rem;

}

.jumbotron{
    padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
}

.header--banner {
    background-image: url(magic.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
.header--banner {

height: 45.5rem;

}

.jumbotron{
    padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
     position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
.green{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Modern;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    background-color:  #27ae60;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  a.green:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:  #145a32;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: 0.7s;
  }

  .bs-example2{
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  text-align: center;
  padding:20px;
  margin:5px;
  height:200px;
  }






</style>

<body>
    <header class="header--banner">

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
             <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="kiosk-HOMEPAGE.php">
                        HOME
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="kiosk-OFFICES.php">Offices</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="kiosk-EMPLOYEES.php">Employees</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="kiosk-EDIT_ADMIN.php"> Change Username & Password</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="kiosk-REPORTS.php">Reports</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="kiosk-login.php">Log Out</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->

        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                 <img src="urdBanner.jpg" id="urdBanner" alt="Banner" style="width:100%; height:250px;"> 
                <center><h2 style="position:relative;">Requirements</h2></center>
                <p></p>


                 <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"><img src="menu.jpg" class="rounded-circle" style="width:30px; height:30px;"></a>
                 <br>
                 <br>
                 <a href="kiosk-charter.php" class="btn btn-default">Previous</a>


        <br>
        <br>

           <form method="get" action="kiosk-NEW_CHARTER_REQUIREMENTS_insert.php">

<input type="hidden" name="office" value="<?php echo $office ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="application_name" value="<?php echo $application_name ?>">



                <br>

                <div class="row form-group">
                     <div class="col-md-2"><label for="textBox" class="col-form-label"><b>Step By Step Procedure</b></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"><label for="textBox" class="col-form-label"><b>Personnel in charge</b></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"><label for="textBox" class="col-form-label"><b>Time needed to complete procedure</b></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"><label for="textBox" class="col-form-label"><b>Amount of fees if any</b></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"><label for="textBox" class="col-form-label"><b>Required Documents</b></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"><label for="textBox" class="col-form-label"><b>Procedure for the filing of complaints</b></label>
                    </div>

            </div>
                </div>

    <div class="form-group fieldGroup">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="steps[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Steps"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="personnel[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Personnel"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="time[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Time"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="fees[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Fees"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="documents[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Documents"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="complaints[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Complaints"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="add" class="btn btn-success addMore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>




<!-- copy of input fields group -->
<div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="steps[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Steps"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="personnel[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Personnel"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="time[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Time"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="fees[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Fees"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="documents[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Documents"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <textarea name="complaints[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" placeholder="Complaints"></textarea>
            </div>
        <div class="input-group-addon"> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT"/>

            </form>


    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>

    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    //group add limit
    var maxGroup = 10;

    //add more fields group
    $(".addMore").click(function(){
        if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup){
            var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
            $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
        }else{
            alert('Maximum '+maxGroup+' groups are allowed.');
        }
    });

    //remove fields group
    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
    });
});


    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
// Auto-Grow-TextArea script.
// Script copyright (C) 2011 www.cryer.co.uk.
// Script is free to use provided this copyright header is included.
function AutoGrowTextArea(textField)
{
  if (textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight)
  {
    textField.style.height = textField.scrollHeight + "px";
    if (textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight)
    {
      textField.style.height = 
        (textField.scrollHeight * 2 - textField.clientHeight) + "px";
    }
  }
}
</script>


     <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>


    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is my insert.php

```
  <?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','information_kiosk');
    $office = $_GET['office'];

    $application_name = $_GET['application_name'];
   $steps = $_GET['steps'];
    $personnel = $_GET['personnel'];
    $time = $_GET['time'];

    $fees = $_GET['fees'];
    $documents = $_GET['documents'];
    $complaints = $_GET['complaints'];


$totalSize = sizeof($steps);

for($i=0;$i <=$totalSize;$i++) {

    $InsertSteps = (!empty($steps[$i])) ? $steps[$i] : '';
    $InsertPersonnel = (!empty($personnel[$i])) ? $personnel[$i] : '';
    $InsertTime = (!empty($time[$i])) ? $time[$i] : '';
     $InsertFees = (!empty($fees[$i])) ? $fees[$i] : '';
    $InsertDocuments = (!empty($documents[$i])) ? $documents[$i] : '';
    $InsertComplaints = (!empty($complaints[$i])) ? $complaints[$i] : '';;

   echo $InsertSteps;
   echo "<br>";
   echo $InsertPersonnel;
    echo $InsertSteps;
   echo "<br>";


}
}
?>
```

*update. with my insert code now it only shows  the first row of data but not the 2nd or 3rd

only the first row gets inserted into database but the following dynamically created rows dont. My question is how could i change my syntax so that each row would insert into the database for example.

```
stepsColumn   PersonnelColumn   timeColumn  feesColumn   documentsColumn  
 array[0]         array[0]      array [0]    array[0]        array[0]
 array[1]         array[1]      array [1]    array[1]        array[1]
```

Comment: Check in developer mode to make sure that when you duplicated the fields, the name was also duplicated. Additionally, check under the Network tab what data has been sent.

Comment: You aren't showing the complete logic. Where does the for loop end? A good practice when debugging is to enter many echo statements. What is count($steps) at the outset?

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Thank you, Yes this is open to SQL injection attack, i will fix that another time. I just need to know how i could insert rows from a dynamically generated textboxes.

Comment: The only thing I really see wrong is the **timee**, specifically `INSERT INTO tbl_charter(steps, personnel, timee, ...)`  Which will give you an unknown column syntax error,  Because looking at the rest of what you have `time[]` and `$time`, I think what you meant is **time**

Comment: You also don't show how you set `$steps` or the others, I'm assuming that is coming from `$_POST['steps']` which should be an array from `name="steps[]"` but who knows.

Comment: Yea sorry im having trouble with posting the whole code im sort of new to this i have updated my code please look

Comment: No "timee" is actually the column i put in phpmyadmin. that is not an error

Comment: I have now successfully shown all of my code.